# Wordpress: Forward slash in post permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, post, permalinks

I am migrating a site from drupal to wordpress and the the drupal posts have a slash in the URL such as
https://example.com/this-is-a-post/xyz-postid

The post_id in the URL is the drupal post ID. When migrating to wordpress since I have to mantain the URLs, I have to include a forward slash in the URL and wordpress does not permit me to save it with slash.

I tried to add a filter to the hook where post link is fetched so that it includes the URL likes this

```
function append_query_string( $url, $post ) {
    $id = get_post_meta($post_id, 'drupal_id', true);
    return $url.'/xyz-'.$id;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

But that does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: It won’t be enough to just modify the links you are creating, you would have to modify how the WP routing process parses incoming requests as well.

Comment: Yep. Or how about if I could just let forward slash to be saved in the URL somehow

Comment: Try your luck with a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/ maybe.

Comment: Forward slash means "next step/child of" But I guess you could add it with https://permalinkmanager.pro/

Comment: @CBroe I wanted to skip using a plugin and do the same using hooks for the post links